# Assign text between tags to an variable

Tags: php, html, variables

Is it possible to get the text between `<p></p>` tags and set this in a variable?

`<p>blabla</p>` So i would like to get the text "blabla" and set this into a php variable so the variable would have the text value like this:.

```
<?$test = blabla;?>
```

Comment: whats your text, pls show it

Comment: You can use DOMDocument, DOMXQuery and their related classes to extract data from HTML/XML documents.

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML in code?  You can use a DOM parser for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$html = "<p>blabla</p>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);

$arr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value->nodeValue; // result => blabla
}
```

There are many methods which can be used based on your needs so take a look on documentation

<kbd>[DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, it is self explanatory:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
 }
?>
```